# Google Ads suddenly disappeared from all apps in production

Tags: android, admob, adsense, google-ads-api

I faced this issue today, suddenly all ads in all my apps which is in production is not displayed any more. When I'm testing in the emulator, I can see ads. However, when I'm checking on my phone, I don't see ads any more. All ads were working fine in all apps till today. I still receive money for ads in AdSense.

I'm using `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'` for ads and pretty standard code to initialize the ads:

```
    MobileAds.initialize(this,
            "ca-app-pub-xxxxx"
    );
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

What can be the problem? Was there any changes in ads sdk?

Comment: write some code then we will analyze the isse

Comment: code is pretty standard, and it was working fine the last one year

Comment: Are the apps published or are you using live ad unit ids on unpublished apps?

Comment: @Ahmad all apps are published in Google play